# Why is the following C code giving such output?

Tags: c

I ran the following code in codeblocks and got the output:
10 20
10 20

```
int main()
{
    int i=10,j=20;
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    printf("%d %d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason of second 20 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're calling `printf` a second time with no intervening code, the value of `j` is still on the stack, left from the previous call.

Of course, you shouldn't depend on this behavior.  Just because you don't *see* the bug doesn't mean it's not there.  :-)

Comment: Shouldn't the second call to `printf` place `i` on stack ?

Answer (score 3):

Reading past the end of vararg list is undefined behavior, so the reason for the second 20 is a pure luck: your code could have printed any integer number, or even crash.

Comment: No, it's not; it's deterministic behavior and probably reproducible on most machines.  The code is incorrect, but its behavior is definitely _not_ due to luck.

Comment: @AdamLiss - it's undefined according to the standard. If your implementation happens to make that deterministic then your implementation makes it deterministic, but it doesn't make it any less undefined from a language perspective.

Comment: That's right.  Undefined, yes.  Luck, or even inconsistent, no.

Comment: (Normally I'd use the term "bad luck" for when undefined behaviour slips by unnoticed - it's bad luck and not good luck if it doesn't happen to crash and you "get away with it" because spotting it earlier/easier is always a good thing)

Comment: @Serious It does not mean anything: I ran your program three times, and got 14754036, 1122548, and 18817268.

Comment: @AdamLiss It's "Yes" on both "luck" and "inconsistent", by the very definition of "undefined behavior". Unspecified behavior is different, but undefined is always non-ambiguously bad.

Comment: I think you'll find that "undefined" and "unspecified" are synonymous. Both mean "We're not going to tell you what happens," not "you can't possibly deduce what will happen."  The practical interpretation is that you shouldn't depend on any particular behavior because there's no contract that it will persist, but neither term means the behavior will _necessarily_ change.  Luck and randomness are certainly not implied.

Comment: @AdamLiss ["undefined" and "unspecified" are most certainly **not** syninymous](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12684). It is very important to keep a firm distinction between the two in your thinking about language features.

Comment: In this case, @dasblinkenlight is pretty much right -- unspecified behavior means you may not know exactly what happens, but whatever it is, it's reasonable and as long as you don't depend on the specific thing that's unspecified, you're fine. A common example is the order of evaluation of parameters to a function. Undefined behavior means *anything* can happen, even things that may seem completely unreasonable. It's not, however, "always non-ambiguously bad" -- sometimes non-portable code depends on it, and it's fine as long as you realize it isn't portable.